# Stepwise creation of one big matrix from smaller matrices in R for-loops

Tags: r, for-loop, matrix

I have the following code:

```
beta <- c(1, 2, 3)
X1 <- matrix(c(1, 1, 1, 1,
               0, 1, 0, 1,
               0, 0, 1, 1),
             nrow = 4,
             ncol = 3)

Z1 <- matrix(c(1, 1, 1, 1,
               0, 1, 0, 1),
             nrow = 4,
             ncol = 2)

Z2 <- matrix(c(1, 1, 1, 1,
               0, 1, 0, 1),
             nrow = 4,
             ncol = 2)

library(MASS)
    S1 <- mvrnorm(70, mu = c(0,0), Sigma = matrix(c(10, 3, 3, 2), ncol = 2))
    S2 <- mvrnorm(40, mu = c(0,0), Sigma = matrix(c(10, 4, 4, 2), ncol = 2))

z <- list()
y <- list()

for(j in 1:dim(S1)[1]){
    for(i in 1:dim(S2)[1]){
        z[[i]] <- X1 %*% beta+Z1 %*% S1[j,]+Z2 %*% S2[i,]+matrix(rnorm(4, mean = 0 , sd = 0.27), nrow = 4)
        Z <- unname(do.call(rbind, z))
    }
    y[[j]] <- Z
    Y <- unname(do.call(rbind, y))
}
```

`X1` is a `4x3`, `Z1` and `Z2` are `4x2` matrices. So everytime `X1 %*% beta+X2 %*% S1[j,]+X2 %*% S2[i,]+matrix(rnorm(4, mean = 0 , sd = sigma), nrow = 4)` is called it outputs a `4x1` matrix. So far I store all these values in the inner and outer loop in two lists and then call `rbind()` to transform them into a matrix. Is there a way to directly store them in matrices?

Comment: it sounds interesting, but I'm finding hard to imagine alternatives without knowing the dimensions of ran_sub, ran_ite and beta.  Could you include a complete example that produces your desired output?

Comment: Of course, one moment please.

Comment: Reproducible example now included.

Comment: still missing `ran_sub` and `ran_ite`. Can I just set them to some small integer?

Comment: Sorry, fixed now. I just replaced `ran_sub` and `ran_ite` with `S1` and `S2` respectively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can avoid using lists if you rely on the `apply` functions and on vector recycling.  I broke down your equation into its parts.  (I hope I interpreted it accurately!)

```
Mb <- as.vector(X1 %*% beta)

M1 <- apply(S1,1,function(x) Z1 %*% x )

M2 <- apply(S2,1,function(x) Z2 %*% x ) + Mb

Mout <- apply(M1,2,function(x) M2 + as.vector(x))

as.vector(Mout) + rnorm(length(Mout), mean = 0 , sd = 0.27)
```

because the random numbers are added *after* the matrix multiplication (ie are not involved in any calculation), you can just put them in on the end.

Also note that you can't add a smaller matrix to a larger one, but if you make it a vector first then R will recycle it as necessary. So when Mb (a vector of length 4) is added to a matrix with 4 rows and n columns, it is recycled n times.

Comment: Thank you. That is a very elegant solution.