# what's wrong of this simple for loop?

Tags: r, for-loop

I am pretty confused by this simple loop. Why doesn't it work?

```
set.seed(123)
out1<-data.frame(y1=rbinom(10, 1, 0.3),
                y2=rbinom(10, 1, 0.4),
                y3=rbinom(10, 1, 0.5),
                y4=rbinom(10, 1, 0.6))

out<-NULL

for(i in 1:10){
  out[i, ]<-out1[i, ]
}
Error in out[i, ] <- out1[i, ] : incorrect number of subscripts on matrix
```

Comment: `out` is not a data.frame, it doesn't have the same dimensions as `out1', you can fix it replacing `out<-NULL`  by `out<-out1*0` and your `for` loop will work.

Comment: out <- out1 does the trick

Answer (score 1):

I would rather take the detour over lists since using `for` loops to create matrices can become quite cumbersome (see e. g. [Stepwise creation of one big matrix from smaller matrices in R for-loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24656439/stepwise-creation-of-one-big-matrix-from-smaller-matrices-in-r-for-loops)). Hence, my solution would be:

```
# Prepare emtpy list:
out <- list()

for(i in 1:10){
   # Store everything in list:
   out[[i]]<-out1[i, ]
   # Bind elements rowwise into matrix:
   Z <- do.call(rbind, out)
 }
```

This will give you a matrix `Z` as output which is identical to the original matrix `out1`. You can verify this by calling `identical(out1, Z)` which will output `TRUE` iff `out1` is identical to `Z`.

Answer (score 1):

This is the way to fix your code without pre-allocating `out` with `dim()` of 10x4. However, note that using `rbind()` is a really inefficient way to code. You should pre-allocate instead.

```
out1<-data.frame(y1=rbinom(10, 1, 0.3),
                 y2=rbinom(10, 1, 0.4),
                 y3=rbinom(10, 1, 0.5),
                 y4=rbinom(10, 1, 0.6))

out<-NULL

for(i in 1:10){
  out <- rbind(out, out1[i, ])
}
```